# jquery-resizable - onDrag event not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am using the jquery-resizable plugin, and I need to inject some code as soon as users stop dragging the splitter. As soon as I add the onDragEnd event, I am not able to drag the handles anymore! I am using the onDragEnd function as listed on Git. Any idea why I am not able to catch that event?

```
onDragEnd: function () {
     alert();
     return false;
});
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mvg0vdm8/2/

Plugin: https://github.com/RickStrahl/jquery-resizable

Comment: And if you comment `return false;`

Comment: Yea, doesn't make a difference...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a syntax error, try this:

```
onDragEnd: function () {
     alert();
     return false;
}
```

Complete `script` (from your fiddle):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".panel-left").resizable({
    handleSelector: ".splitter",
    resizeHeight: false,
    onDragEnd: function () {
     alert();
     return false;
    }
  });

  $(".panel-top").resizable({
    handleSelector: ".splitter-horizontal",
    resizeWidth: false,
    onDragEnd: function () {
     alert();
     return false;
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Still doesn't work. Did it work for you in the fiddle?

Comment: Yes, it did, i'll add one.

Comment: Thanks. I was adding the function outside of the .resizable! :/